# Blazor not setting new generated values

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

When I am generating new times for the Day object from my Helper class, times count always is 0.

This is my Day class

```
public class Day
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Massage> Massages { get; set; } = new List<Massage>();
    public List<DateTime> Times { get; set; } = new List<DateTime>();     
}
```

This is my Helper class and generateTimes method

```
public class Helper
{
    public Helper()
    {

    }

    public void generateTimes( Day day)
    {
        if (day.Massages?.Any() ?? false)
        {
            day.Times = new List<DateTime>();
            List<DateTime> newTimes = new List<DateTime>();
            newTimes.AddRange(new List<DateTime>
            {
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 8, 0, 0),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 8, 30, 0),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 9, 0, 0),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 9, 30, 0),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,10,0,0),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,10,30,0),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,11,0,0),
                new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,11,30,0)
            });
            day.Times = newTimes;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my index.razor where I want to show the count of available times for the date.

```
<div class="control-section">
    <div id="wrapper" class="datepicker-section">
        <div id="datepicker-control">
            <EjsDatePicker @bind-Value="@Date1" id="datepicker" placeholder="Choose date"></EjsDatePicker>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<span>
    @if (Date1.HasValue)
    {
        Helper helper = new Helper();


        @if (days.Find(d => d.Date.Day == Date1.Value.Day && d.Date.Month == Date1.Value.Month && d.Date.Year == Date1.Value.Year) == null)
        {

            Day day = new Day();
            day.Date = Date1.Value;

            //Generating Times
            helper.generateTimes( day);
            days.Add(day);

            <p>@day.Date</p>

            //Needs to be 8
            <p>@day.Times.Count</p>

            foreach (DateTime t in day.Times)
            {
                <p>@t.Hour</p>
                <p>@t.Minute</p>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <p>@days.Find(d => d.Date.Day == Date1.Value.Day && d.Date.Month == Date1.Value.Month && d.Date.Year == Date1.Value.Year).Times.Count</p>
            @foreach (DateTime t in @days.Find(d => d.Date.Day == Date1.Value.Day && d.Date.Month == Date1.Value.Month && d.Date.Year == Date1.Value.Year).Times)
            {
                <p>@t.Hour</p>
                <p>@t.Minute</p>
            }
        }
    }
</span>
@code
      {
    public DateTime? Date1 { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public List<Day> days = new List<Day>();
}
```

It works when I make the same method in the index.razor

Comment: quick potential issue is with line " if (day.Massages?.Any() ?? false)". That means that the content where you are populating will only add the items if there are already items in the collection... which there wont be (From code posted, it's initialised but has no data).

I suspect you want "if (!day.Massages.Any())" or remove the if statement